# Auth with roles management through apache2 reverse-proxy

Tags: permissions, authentication, reverse-proxy, apache-2.4

Initially [posted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648364/auth-with-roles-management-through-apache2-reverse-proxy) ,but I guess it belongs more here. Suggestions, comments, and ideally solutions, would be welcome !
(btw, I'll delete SO Thread if it was the wrong place)

I need to set-up a reverse-proxy to provide a restricted access from outside to an internal server.
Here are the main requirements:

- Redirect requests from https://www.example.com to the http://internalserver (done)
- Rely on a simple yet proven auth mechanism. (currently working)
- Manage user roles by adding some GET parameters to the URL. (but how ?)
- *The server is hosting a java application.  I don't have access to it yet, and it's app code is not to be changed.  This shouldn't matter.*

I installed and configured *mod_proxy*, and the redirect works fine.

The auth is using apache2 *basic auth*, which should be enough in terms of security.

Now, my problem is roles management.  I need to alter requests so that user foo has admin privileges, while user bar doesn't.  It should be as simple as setting one GET parameter like `"&role=admin"`, but I don't know how to do this when proxying requests.

The roles are currently stored in a dedicated MySQL database, so getting the privileges just needs a request, easily done in PHP.  My problem is that I don't know how to keep the proxy behaviour if I call a php page.  I want every request to have the role parameter(s) append, but need to keep the rest of the request unaltered.

My current proxy does everything with virtualhost configuration (alias .htaccess), but I have no idea of what approach could work.  I can't do MySQL requests in VHost, and redirecting to a php page would - *as far as I know* - "break" the proxy concept, since I would redirect, but probably lose "other request parameters", which is not very clear to me, since I never used proxies.

<s>`libapache2-mod-auth-mysql` might have been a solution, but the mod seems discontinued, so I couldn't even try it</s>. Could mod_authn_dbd be a solution ? So far, I didn't manage to login using it, but, I'm not sure it could solve my need of adding a get parameter, anyway.

I'm running out of ideas.

How could I implement what I need ?  I'm pretty sure an easy solution exists for such a common need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that comes to mind is to write your own simple proxy, for example on php/curl. Apache will serve as a php-enabled web server, and php/curl will proxy requests and modify the GET parameters, according to the username supplied. You could even make cookie-enable authentication, not only HTTP one.

You can also try the same thing using nginx, HTTP authentication and nginx lua module, but this is basically same stuff, minus the necessity to write proxy in lua - lua will only decide is the user worth admin role or not, and nginx will proxy requests and modify GET args.